# Can't copy internal file to user's computer

Tags: java, file

I have a program that requires that an internal file (DICTIONARY) be copied to the user's computer into the folder defined like so:

```
  private static final String  DIC_NAME   = "WordHelp.dic";
  private static final String  DIC_FOLDER = System.getProperty("user.home");
  private static final String  PATH_SEP   = System.getProperty("file.separator");
  public  static final String  DICTIONARY = DIC_FOLDER + PATH_SEP + DIC_NAME;
```

Here's what works on MY computer, where all the Java stuff is:

```
  public static void createDictionaryIfNecessary() throws IOException{

    Path out_path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(DICTIONARY);

    boolean dic_exists = Files.exists(out_path, 
                                  new LinkOption[]{LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS});
    if(dic_exists)
      return;

    File file = new File("src/dictionary");  // here's problem for user ************

    Path in_path = file.toPath();

    try {
      Files.copy(in_path, out_path, 
                          REPLACE_EXISTING, COPY_ATTRIBUTES, NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
    } catch (IOException e) {    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);    }
  }
```

But user gets this error:

```
  java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:  src\dictionary
```

SOURCE file (internal to .jar file) can't be found.

If I look at `in_path` while debugging, the value is:

```
  (sun.nio.fs.Windowspath) src/dictionary
```

And below is a bunch of info about in_path:

[image]

This all works on MY computer and I could  have sworn that it ONCE worked on a user's computer...

**How should I define** `file` (see line with ********** to enable copying internal file (`src/dictionary`) onto a user's computer?

Here's Netbeans project view:

[image]

Comment: You should open it as a resource if it's bundled in the apps classpath.

Comment: @DaveNewton--this is where I need help: the syntax of opening a resource. I'm Googling... it's not helping. (And what does the apps classpath have to do with user's computer?) I'm lost, here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it by using a `Scanner` to read individual strings from the internal file instead of using `Files.copy`. Here's the code. (It's not quite as fast using `Scanner`, but it works.)

```
  public static void write(FileOutputStream outfile, String s) {
    try {
      for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        outfile.write(s.charAt(i));
      outfile.write(13); outfile.write(10);
    } catch (IOException ex) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);}
  } 

  public static Scanner openDic(){
    InputStream myStream = null;
    try { myStream =  Class.forName("masterwords.Masterwords").getClassLoader()
                      .getResourceAsStream("dictionary"); 
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {/* ... */}
    return new Scanner(myStream).useDelimiter("\r");
  }

  public static void createDictionaryIfNecessary(){

    Path out_path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(DICTIONARY);

    if(Files.exists(out_path, new LinkOption[]{LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS})) return;

    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {outStream = new FileOutputStream(out_path.toFile());} 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);}

    Scanner scInternalDic = IO.openDic();
    while(scInternalDic.hasNext()){
      Utilities.write(outStream,scInternalDic.next());
    }

    try {outStream.close();} 
    catch (IOException ex) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);}
    scInternalDic.close();
  }
```

Comment: I don't really like this solution, since the code is 3 times as long as what I had. I'd like to see a modification to original code to solve the problem, if possible. Either way, I'm finished.